# Negative margin and background image not displaying properly

Tags: css, image, background, margin

Hi I am trying to create a background image at the bottom left of my page. The page has a left and right sidebar. I have used css to place the image in the left sidebar and in the main content and neither are sitting properly.

Here is what I want it to look like: http://www.onetreehill.net.au/images/image2.jpg (The girl down the bottom. I want her to site at the very bottom left of the page, no matter how long the page is.)

And this is how she is sitting at the moment with the CSS I have used: http://www.onetreehill.net.au/images/image1.jpg

The CSS I have used:

```
.Content {
background: url(../../__custom/images/blue/page-bottom-1.jpg) left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
overflow: visible;
}

.Left {
background: url(../../__custom/images/blue/page-bottom-1.jpg) left bottom;
background-repeat: no-repeat; 
overflow: visible;
}
```

When I use the following as background position: background:

```
url(../../__custom/images/blue/page-bottom-1.jpg) -150px 100%;
```

Comment: please show you code/fiddle/demo site so we can easily point out where exactly you are facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us your HTML? My suspicion is that `.Left` is not reaching all the way to the bottom of the column but it's hard to say without seeing the markup.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to answer if you can show your html . One thing you can try is to give the background image to the main container div (probably the parent of the left div) .

if your code is like this

```
<div class="main-container">
   <div class="left"></div>
   <div class="content"></div>
   <div class="right">
```

then your style would be

```
.main-continer {

 background: url(../../__custom/images/blue/page-bottom-1.jpg)no-repeat scroll  left bottom ;
}
```

Hope this helps..